# Sort alphabetically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

How do I sort an array in Rails (alphabetical order). I have tried:

```
sort_by(&:field_name)
```

which that gives me an array with capital letter order and then lower case order. I have tried:

```
array.sort! { |x,y| x.field_name.downcase <=> y.field_name.downcase }
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: please paste your sample array.

Comment: sample array[john,Alice,Joseph,anna,Zilhan] i want the result as [Alice,anna,john,Joseph,Zilhan]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should first downcase every string and then sort like:

```
array = ["john", "Alice", "Joseph", "anna", "Zilhan"]
array.sort_by!{ |e| e.downcase }
=> ["Alice", "anna", "john", "Joseph", "Zilhan"]
```

Comment: you just made a mistake. sort_by! will sort the array object itself.

Comment: Yes i know that, it depends on the requirement, you may also use: new_array = array.sort_by{ |e| e.downcase } , but only if old array required further otherwise its useless to create another object.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware - names can contain special characters. These will be sorted to the end.

```
>> ["Ägidius", "john", "Alice", "Zilhan"].sort_by!{ |e| e.downcase }
=> ["Alice", "john", "Zilhan", "Ägidius"]
```

To cover this, you can use...

```
>> ["Ägidius", "john", "Alice", "Zilhan"].sort_by!{ |e| ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(e.downcase) }
=> ["Ägidius", "Alice", "john", "Zilhan"]
```