# How to sort @users.person.name by name? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to sort @users by name alphabetically. How would I do that?

@users.person.name

EDIT:
Here is how I solved this:
@users.sort! { |a, b| a.person.name <=> b.person.name }

Thank you num8er

Comment: Learn ruby: https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/07/ruby-sort/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort alphabetically in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441435/sort-alphabetically-in-rails)

Comment: Simple and straightforward: `sort` with `spaceship operator`.
`@users.sort! { |a, b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase }` or `@users.sort_by!{ |user| user.name.downcase }` if name consist of firstname and lastname then split it: `@users.sort_by!{ |user| user.name.split(' ')[0] }`

Comment: `Users.joins(:person).order(people: { name: :asc})`? This assumes `@users` is a collection of `User` AR objects

Comment: What is `@users`? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

One observations on your solution. If you use `#sort!` instead of `#sort` you'll want to have a good reason why; `#sort` is preferable unless you need `#sort!`.

Consider this code:

```
    1  test = %w(c a b)
    2  p test.sort  # => ['a', 'b', 'c']
    3  p test       # => ["c", "a", "b"]
    4  p test.sort! # => ['a', 'b', 'c']
    5  p test       # => ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you don't know why line 5 shows a different value from line 3, then I would suggest that you avoid using `#sort!` altogether until you do. Otherwise, you could create some very difficult-to-find bugs.

Comment: The block is absolutely necessary because the OP wants to sort by "name" which appears to be an attribute (method) of the return value from the `person` method. `@users.sort` would have no knowledge of this unless you overwrote the `<=>` (spaceship operator) method in what ever objects are contained in the `@users` collection.

Comment: @engineersmnky Absolutely correct, my mistake. I've removed the first point (which, for anyone reading this, said you didn't need the block, and you do). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort`, but that requires first fetching all the Users. If there are many Users this can eat a lot of memory.

Instead, you can do the sorting in the database and fetch them in order on demand.

```
@users = User
  .joins(:person)        # join by the model name
  .order("people.name")  # order by the table name

# find_each is more efficient than each for large sets
@users.find_each do |user|
  ...do something with each user...
end
```

And you can put it in a [scope](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) to use anywhere.

```
class User
  scope :by_name, ->() { joins(:person).order("people.name") }
end

# Find the first 10 users, ordered by their name.
@users = User.by_name.limit(10)
```